# Pandas: Sum Based on two columns (columns don`t match in same row)

Tags: python, pandas

I´m trying to find a way to have a new column (Duration_Week_N+1) based on other column (Device_Week)

I have the following pandas DataFrame.

```
    Device  Duration   DeviceVSweek     DeviceVSweek_N+1
      452     17461       452_1             452_2  
      452      2962       452_2             452_3 
      452      5370       452_3             452_4
```

I'm unable to find a way where I can assume Duration_Week_N+1 is based on DeviceVSweek

This is the expected result

```
Device  Duration   DeviceVSweek     DeviceVSweek_N+1    Duration_Week_N+1
  452     17461       452_1              452_2               2962
  452      2962       452_2              452_3               5370
  452      5370       452_3              452_4                0
```

I tried using loc which obviously didn't work as it looks for a line match between DeviceVSweek and DeviceVSweek_N+1 (does not exist)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `shift`:

```
df["Duration_Week_N+1"] = df["Duration"].shift(-1).fillna(0)
>>> df
   Device  Duration DeviceVSweek DeviceVSweek_N+1  Duration_Week_N+1
0     452     17461        452_1            452_2             2962.0
1     452      2962        452_2            452_3             5370.0
2     452      5370        452_3            452_4                  0
```

Edit:
If your `df` has missing (non-consecutive) weeks such that `shift` won't work, try:

```
df["Duration_Week_N+1"] = df["DeviceVSweek_N+1"].map(dict(zip(df["DeviceVSweek"], df["Duration"])))
```

`dict(zip)` creates a dictionary with keys as DeviceVSweet and values as Duration. `map` then maps each row of "DeviceVSweet_N+1" using the created dictionary.

Comment: It doesn't work if a week is missing. Imagine the index 2 is `(452_4, 452_5)`

Comment: Agreed @Corralien - Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you! it worked! Is it possible to explain the rational to me? map...? zip...? dict? or forward me to some link? I think there are too many pieces involved for my level of knowledge (basic)

Comment: Added a brief explanation but you may also want to see [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip). `dict` is just a datatype in Python which you should probably know if you're already using DataFrames.